# WPF WebView2 Error - source property cannot be set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

To authenticate an API service, it is required for the user to sign into a webpage. If the sign-in is valid, an authentication code is appended to the end of a redirected Uri. The authentication code is then used in the oauth to get the key, etc... To faciliate this, I have implemented WebView2:

```
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"
                  Width="800"
                  Height="500"
                  Source="{Binding WebUri, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SourceChangedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </wv2:WebView2>
```

I have validation logic in the viewmodel to recognize when the redirect uri contains the authentication code; this is done through the `SourceChangedCommand` that is called when the SourceChanged event is thrown on the WebView (following the navigation event lifecycle described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events)). The `SourceChangedCommand.Execute` is as follows:

```
    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        if (ValidateUri(_viewModel.WebUri.ToString()))
        {
            var str = _viewModel.WebUri.ToString().Substring(50);
            _navigationService.Authenticate(str);
        }
    }
```

**Here is where I am running into a problem:**
I also have a NavigationService which navigates between viewmodels and changes view by datatemplates, etc... When navigating away from the view with the WebView2 (ie: changing data contexts on the parent view), I am given the following error:

> The Source property cannot be set to null

[image]

This is extremely confusing as the source for the WebView2 is never actually set to null - it is maintained as the redirected Uri. **What is going wrong here and how can I navigate away from this view?**

Possible solutions I am exploring is creating a custom control extending WebView2 with a bool dependency property mapped to WebView2.Dispose(bool) -> if true, the webview will be disposed. This however seems like overkill and might bring up other issues relating to `ObjectDisposedException`'s.

Comment: You may consider posting your issue here: [WebView2 Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found it was because I was setting `IsAsync=true` on the binding.

Also inspect the properties you are binding to.  They always need to be able to get a value that isn't null.

When my properties are initialized I set them to new `Uri("about:blank")`.
Additionally, use
`this._myProp = new UriBuilder(value).Uri ?? new Uri("about:blank")` on the field set to ensure no nulls

Hey Microsoft how about a static `Uri.Empty` property with about:blank in it?

I hope this helps